# Link a CMSIS Driver structure to CMSIS Cortex-M4 Peripheral

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, texas-instruments, cmsis

I was wondering how can I link a CMSIS Driver, for example I2C Driver data structure, to its physical peripheral ?

So here is the structure in **Driver_I2C.h**

```
typedef struct _ARM_DRIVER_I2C {
  ARM_DRIVER_VERSION   (*GetVersion)     (void);                                                                ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_GetVersion : Get driver version.
  ARM_I2C_CAPABILITIES (*GetCapabilities)(void);                                                                ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_GetCapabilities : Get driver capabilities.
  int32_t              (*Initialize)     (ARM_I2C_SignalEvent_t cb_event);                                      ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_Initialize : Initialize I2C Interface.
  int32_t              (*Uninitialize)   (void);                                                                ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_Uninitialize : De-initialize I2C Interface.
  int32_t              (*PowerControl)   (ARM_POWER_STATE state);                                               ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_PowerControl : Control I2C Interface Power.
  int32_t              (*MasterTransmit) (uint32_t addr, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t num, bool xfer_pending); ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_MasterTransmit : Start transmitting data as I2C Master.
  int32_t              (*MasterReceive)  (uint32_t addr,       uint8_t *data, uint32_t num, bool xfer_pending); ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_MasterReceive : Start receiving data as I2C Master.
  int32_t              (*SlaveTransmit)  (               const uint8_t *data, uint32_t num);                    ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_SlaveTransmit : Start transmitting data as I2C Slave.
  int32_t              (*SlaveReceive)   (                     uint8_t *data, uint32_t num);                    ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_SlaveReceive : Start receiving data as I2C Slave.
  int32_t              (*GetDataCount)   (void);                                                                ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_GetDataCount : Get transferred data count.
  int32_t              (*Control)        (uint32_t control, uint32_t arg);                                      ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_Control : Control I2C Interface.
  ARM_I2C_STATUS       (*GetStatus)      (void);                                                                ///< Pointer to \ref ARM_I2C_GetStatus : Get I2C status.
} const ARM_DRIVER_I2C;
```

I create a variable that use this structure in my **main.c** :

```
ARM_DRIVER_I2C Driver_I2C0; //Create a instance of I2C0
```

But how do I link that variable to the CMSIS Cortex M4 peripherical I2C0 ? (**TM4C123GH6PM.h**)

```
 typedef struct {                                    /*!< I2C0 Structure                                                        */
  __IO uint32_t  MSA;                               /*!< I2C Master Slave Address                                              */

  union {
    __IO uint32_t  MCS_I2C0_ALT;                    /*!< I2C Master Control/Status                                             */
    __IO uint32_t  MCS;                             /*!< I2C Master Control/Status                                             */
  };
  __IO uint32_t  MDR;                               /*!< I2C Master Data                                                       */
  __IO uint32_t  MTPR;                              /*!< I2C Master Timer Period                                               */
  __IO uint32_t  MIMR;                              /*!< I2C Master Interrupt Mask                                             */
  __IO uint32_t  MRIS;                              /*!< I2C Master Raw Interrupt Status                                       */
  __IO uint32_t  MMIS;                              /*!< I2C Master Masked Interrupt Status                                    */
  __O  uint32_t  MICR;                              /*!< I2C Master Interrupt Clear                                            */
  __IO uint32_t  MCR;                               /*!< I2C Master Configuration                                              */
  __IO uint32_t  MCLKOCNT;                          /*!< I2C Master Clock Low Timeout Count                                    */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED0;
  __IO uint32_t  MBMON;                             /*!< I2C Master Bus Monitor                                                */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED1[2];
  __IO uint32_t  MCR2;                              /*!< I2C Master Configuration 2                                            */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED2[497];
  __IO uint32_t  SOAR;                              /*!< I2C Slave Own Address                                                 */

  union {
    __IO uint32_t  SCSR_I2C0_ALT;                   /*!< I2C Slave Control/Status                                              */
    __IO uint32_t  SCSR;                            /*!< I2C Slave Control/Status                                              */
  };
  __IO uint32_t  SDR;                               /*!< I2C Slave Data                                                        */
  __IO uint32_t  SIMR;                              /*!< I2C Slave Interrupt Mask                                              */
  __IO uint32_t  SRIS;                              /*!< I2C Slave Raw Interrupt Status                                        */
  __IO uint32_t  SMIS;                              /*!< I2C Slave Masked Interrupt Status                                     */
  __O  uint32_t  SICR;                              /*!< I2C Slave Interrupt Clear                                             */
  __IO uint32_t  SOAR2;                             /*!< I2C Slave Own Address 2                                               */
  __IO uint32_t  SACKCTL;                           /*!< I2C Slave ACK Control                                                 */
  __I  uint32_t  RESERVED3[487];
  __IO uint32_t  PP;                                /*!< I2C Peripheral Properties                                             */
  __IO uint32_t  PC;                                /*!< I2C Peripheral Configuration                                          */
} I2C0_Type;
```

**Question** : Does the CMSIS template have a way to handle that link or do I need to do it myself, by adding a pointer to that M4 Cortex Structure for example ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I cant see what one thing has to do with the other.   One is registers that need a driver if you will to make them work the other is related to some high level library(/driver).  So you have to fill in the gap with chip/peripheral specific code.  Which ti should have provided.  Just uses ti's sandbox if you dont want to configure the peripheral yourself.

Comment: Well if i understand correctly I have to fill the gap in Driver_I2C.c where are specified the functions
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/driver/html/Driver__I2C_8c.html

But if i need to make that library portable i need to specify somewhere the peripherical to use right ?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel, if you feel the need to use CMSIS just use the code from ti, including any sandbox and examples.  Or avoid CMSIS and use the peripheral directly or use a pre-cmsis library (from ti of course).

Comment: What is wrong with ti's solution that you are trying to do something else?  What about it wont work for you?

Comment: I was just curious about how CMSIS work :D, so I made some small project to get more familiar/comfortable with embedded programming. Thanks for the answers, if you have some usefull website about embedded programming/ARM I am really interested !

Comment: arm is just the core inside the chip it is just purchased ip, the bulk of the code is related to peripherals in the chip which are either also purchased ip from some other third party or ip from the chip vendor (ti, nxp, st, etc).  to configure and use those peripherals you need code from the chip vendor or documentation that you simply read and configure the peripheral by talking to the registers.

Comment: these vendors will provide sandboxes, tools and libraries and usually an ide, to hold your hand through the process, not the best code usually, but tolerable.  You simply get the code from the chip vendor, the whole sandbox and go from there, you can then dig through the code to see how it works.  Starting with one of their examples.

Comment: If you start from arm or a compiler end of things and not from the chip vendor that takes experience and often you just dont want to use that code and roll your own.  Professionally should try to learn both paths, roll your own and use the sandbox, but start with the sandbox code and read through it and compare what you see to the (hardware) documentation from ti and arm.  you will want a scope if you want to mess with i2c, they are quite affordable now for these speeds.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, i'll do that way, seems more appropriate for a beginner !

Comment: I think thats why some folks use the term sandbox.  A safer place as a beginner as you advance, you build your own sandbox or get out of the sandbox.  Can remove the training wheels, etc.  And take responsibility for the additional challenges in those situations.

Comment: As much as you want to dive in and start changing things, do your best to use their stuff as is, see that it works (if not use their support resources to resolve it), and then you have a working baseline to fall back on if you break things when you modify them.